# как передать параметром в генератор функцию-фильтр?

Tags: python, python-3.x

есть генератор простых чисел:

```
def prime_numbers_generator(n):
    prime_numbers = []
    for number in range(2, n + 1):
        for prime in prime_numbers:
            if number % prime == 0:
                break
        else:
            prime_numbers.append(number)
            yield str(number)
```

есть функция-фильтр, которая ищет "счастливые числа"(

727 -> 7(2)7 -> 7 == 7 -> счастливое

92083 -> 92(0)83 -> 9+2 == 8+3 -> счастливое):

```
def sum_digits(digit):
    return sum(map(int, digit))


def is_lucky(digit):
    middle = len(digit) // 2
    return sum_digits(digit[:middle]) == sum_digits(digit[-middle:])
```

как мне передать параметром эту функцию-фильтр в генератор?
пробовал как написано ниже. не получилось

```
После добавления в список, в самом коде генератора
Надо добавить проверку, если число счастливое - добавить к числу подпись 151 - счастливое
И получившуюся строку уже выводить yield-ом
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def prime_numbers_generator(n, check):
    prime_numbers = []
    for number in range(2, n + 1):
        for prime in prime_numbers:
            if number % prime == 0:
                break
        else:
            prime_numbers.append(number)
            if check(str(number)):
                yield str(number)

def sum_digits(digit):
    return sum(map(int, digit))


def is_lucky(digit):
    middle = len(digit) // 2
    return sum_digits(digit[:middle]) == sum_digits(digit[-middle:])

for x in  prime_numbers_generator(1000, is_lucky):
    print(x)
```

Comment: всё оказалось довольно просто) спасибо!